# Unable to make bidirectional many-to-many tables

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

While trying to make a blog flask application, I wanted to add a new table with different roles users can have. Users can have one or many roles, which is why the roles column in the user table is a list(as shown below).

```
roles_user_table = db.Table(
    "roles_user_table",
    db.metadata, 
    sa.Column("user_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("role_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("role.id"), primary_key=True)
)

class User(fsqla.FsUserMixin, db.Model):
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    email: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash: so.Mapped[Optional[str]] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(256))
    posts: so.WriteOnlyMapped['Post'] = so.relationship(back_populates='author')
    about_me: so.Mapped[Optional[str]] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(140))
    last_seen: so.Mapped[Optional[datetime]] = so.mapped_column(default=lambda: datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    role: so.Mapped[list['Role']] = so.relationship("Role", secondary=roles_user_table,
                                                        primaryjoin=(roles_user_table.c.user_id == id), 
                                                        secondaryjoin=(roles_user_table.c.role_id == id),
                                                        back_populates="name")

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.email)
    
    def avatar(self, size):
        digest = md5(self.email.lower().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        return f'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{digest}?d=identicon&s={size}'
    
class Post(db.Model):
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    body: so.Mapped[str] = so.mapped_column(sa.String(140))
    timestamp: so.Mapped[datetime] = so.mapped_column(index=True, default=lambda: datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    user_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(sa.ForeignKey(User.id), index=True)
    author: so.Mapped[User] = so.relationship(back_populates='posts')

    def __rep__(self):
        return '<Post {}>'.format(self.body)
    
class Role(db.Model, fsqla.FsRoleMixin):
    id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: so.Mapped[list[User]] = so.relationship(sa.String(140), secondary=roles_user_table, back_populates="role")

    def __rep__(self):
        return '<Role {}>'.format(self.name)
```

When trying to add a role to my roles table running the command:

```
admin = Role(name="admin")
```

I get the error:

```
can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper[User(user)]'. Original exception was: relationship 'name' 
expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.String'>)
```

what do I have to change in models to be able to add roles to my User Model ?